# Problemas con ImageIcon

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

Hola este es el ejercicio 9.8 de Como Programar en JAVA de Deitel Edicion 10
no logro que se visualicen el icono "GUItip.gif"

asi esta guardado el GIF

[image: Asi esta guargado el GIF]

Aqui al lado de las dos etiquetas deberia aparecer el gif
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el GIF
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;



public class GUIJLabel {


public static void main(String[] args) {
  //crea una etiqueta con texto solamente
  JLabel etiquetaNorte = new JLabel("Norte");  

  //crea un icono a partir de una imagen para poder colocarla en un objeto
ImageIcon etiquetaIcono = new ImageIcon("GUItip.gif");

//crea una etiqueta con un icono en vez de texto
JLabel etiquetaCentro = new JLabel(etiquetaIcono);

//crea otra etiqueta con un icono
JLabel etiquetaSur = new JLabel(etiquetaIcono);

//establece la etiqueta para mostrar texto(asi como un icono)
etiquetaSur.setText("Sur");

//crea un marco para contener las etiquetas
JFrame aplicacion = new JFrame();
aplicacion.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

//agrega las etiquetas al marco;el segundo argumento especifica
//en que parte del marco se va a agregar la etiqueta
aplicacion.add(etiquetaNorte,BorderLayout.NORTH);
aplicacion.add(etiquetaCentro,BorderLayout.CENTER);
aplicacion.add(etiquetaSur,BorderLayout.SOUTH);


  aplicacion.setSize(400,400);
  aplicacion.setVisible(true);
  }

}
```

Comment: Probablemente necesites dejar la imagen en una ruta que se encuentre en el classpath. Prueba agregarla en una carpeta de recursos de tu IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es un error de rutas para obtener la imagen en sí , al hacer simplemente `ImageIcon etiquetaIcono = new ImageIcon("GUItip.gif");` lo que hace es buscar el archivo de imagen en la carpeta root de su proyecto , pero según la imagen esto no es así. Lo cuál teniendo esto claro surgen dos soluciones

- Mover la imagen a la carpeta root de tu proyecto si es NetBeans seguro es en `C:\Users\TUUSUARIO\Documents\NetBeansProjects\NombreProyecto`
- Obtener el recurso de un paquete como muestra la imagen sería necesario utilizar `getResource` y acceder a su imagen , *(Ojo esto funcionará solo si la clase y la imagen están en un mismo paquete , como es el caso de su ejemplo)*
  , *Ejm*

  ```
  URL urlimagen = GUIJLabel.class.getResource("GUItip.gif");
  //crea un icono a partir de una imagen para poder colocarla en un objeto
  ImageIcon etiquetaIcono = new ImageIcon(urlimagen);
  ```

Comment: si,ahora funciona,puse el gif en la carpeta root y no en /src,y anduvo,muchas gracias a los dos!

Answer (score 0):

ami también me funcionó. Sólamente fue copias las imagnes a la carpeta netbeansprojects, luego en las propiedades jlabel agrego el icono como External Image y listo.

Comment: Eso es más un comentario que una respuesta, por favor lee [answer] y evita usar el área de respuestas para comentarios. Saludos.