# error: at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)

Tags: java, netbeans, imagen

Cuando quiere mostrar la imagen me aparece ese error, intento llamarla atraves de un label y luego en insertar icono.

La imagen esta en el directorio src, deberia moverla algun otro directorio?

Este es el trozo de codigo en el cual llamo a dicha imagen.

```
galaxy = new javax.swing.JLabel();

galaxy.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images_proy/galaxy1.png"))); // NOI18N

// Code adding the component to the parent container - not shown here
```

Comment: tu mensaje de error está incompleto

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problemas con ImageIcon](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145114/problemas-con-imageicon)